# Include a css file into the header of the view that's calling a controller method

Tags: php, laravel

Basically what I'm trying to do is to implement a little chunk of html generated by a controller in a separate view into one main view. The problem is that I need custom styles for that little chunk of html and I can't know where I'll have to include it (manually), so I'd like the css to get appended to the file calling the function somehow from the controller when the method is being called.
More detailed explanation:
I'm programatically listing small custom panels to display some properties of each instance of my model (in this case, a window). In the main view, where I'm listing, there are a lot of them, so I decided to make a separate view file to create the panel and then simply return it via a function in the controller.
So in the `home.blade.php` I do as follows:

```
@foreach($order -> windows as $window)
    {!!$window->drawPanel()!!}
@endforeach
```

Then in my Window controller I've got a method to return the view where the window is being displayed (!differently depeding on it's properties!) like that:

```
public function drawPanel()
{
    return view('dogrami.windowPanelThumbnail', ['window' => $this]);
}
```

And then in the `windowPanelThumbnail` file I'm displaying accordingly the html needed. The problem is: to build my panel, I use some custom css which I can't include in the builder view, because it's getting called like 100 times.
The question is - how to append the style to the file that called the method in the controller.
Basically I'd like to do as follows:

```
public function drawPanel()
{
    //$cssFile = pathToMyCssFile;//that's the instance containing my custom css
    //$callingFile = ...//somehow retrieve an instance to the file that called that method.. in this case - the path to 'home.blade.php'
    //if($calling.File already has the $cssFile included in it's header)
        //don't do anything
    //else
        //$callingFile -> somehow include the $cssFile instance in the header
    return view('dogrami.windowPanelThumbnail', ['window' => $this]);
}
```

I have no idea if it's possible so that's what I'm asking. Or if you have better ideas of how to achieve that, I'd be really thankful!

Comment: Do you have a layout file ?

Comment: @AlexvanVliet I'm sticking to my only app file in the layouts, it's an option! Thanks! But my question is about the way to achieve what I asked, although you solved my problem with that reminder. I mean, I might need it for future use and I'd like to be able to do as described. Also, how can I include the css file programatically in the header or should I simply use the `File` facade to write directly into the file? Because I'd need a check as well.

Comment: Do you include the view or do you yield it ?

Comment: @AlexvanVliet I'm returning the single little views from a controller method, whilst they're being listed in a main view, that actually extends the main layout

Comment: Well the question really is whether or not the functions that add the css files are called before the </head> is written or after ?

Comment: Afterwards, in the body of one of the containers

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include your css dynamically you can use stacks https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#stacks this way :

```
$links = ["all", "the", "links", "to", "css", "files"];
return view('yourview', [/*allyourdata, */, 'stylesheets' => $links]);
```

And in your view you can do :

```
@push('stylesheets')
    @foreach($stylesheets as $stylesheet)
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ $stylesheet }}">
    @endforeach
@endpush
```

And add `@stack('stylesheets')` in the head of your html

PS : a stack is a lifo data structure (last in first out), meaning that if you do several @push, the last one you do will be the first one echo'ed

Comment: The problem is I don't actually know which view is calling the method... And in my controller I'm also not returning the main view, but the panel builder view, to which I don't have to add any css.

Comment: Oh I didn't really understand your question, I have now, I'll edit my answer once I've tested it